# Problema con histogramas

Tags: r

Estoy haciendo un histograma de una distribución binomial aleatoria y al representar los valores, las barras salen separadas. Sé que es un problema con el comando 'breaks' pero no logro dar con la cifra adecuada.

Ejemplo de datos:

```
set.seed(0)
distribucion2 <- rbinom(5000,5,.4)
hist(distribucion2)
```

Resultado obtenido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Bienvenido @JaimeSerrano a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Sería bueno que incluyas el código y los datos --aunque estos son aleatorios no sé si estes usando un `set.seed()`- con el que se generó el gráfico para orientarte mejor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que en este caso, más allá del código hay que tener en cuenta que la [distribución binomial](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuci%C3%B3n_binomial) es **discreta**, por ende las frecuencias corresponden a un único punto y no a un intervalo.

En tal sentido, el gráfico que se muestra en la pregunta, cuando se emplea `hist`, **R** interpreta que no hay datos entre 0.5 y 1.5 por ejemplo y por ello se muestran los vacios respectivos en la figura.

No obstante lo anterio, **R base** posee dos tipos de gráficos que ayudan a sortear dicha situación: `Plot` y `Bar plot`

```
set.seed(0)  # fijamos los numeros aleatorios

x <- rbinom(5000,5,.4) # se genera una muestra de 5000 para los valores que van del
                       # 0 al 5 con una probabilidad de 0.4

frec <- table(x) # se calcula los acumulados (frecuencias) para 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 y 5
frec
#   0    1    2    3    4    5 
# 423 1283 1682 1145  414   53 

par(mfcol=c(1,2)) # una fila por dos columnas para los dos graficos es opcional

plot(frec, ylab = "Frecuencia", xlab = "Distribucion 2", main="Plot")
barplot(frec, ylab = "Frecuencia", xlab = "Distribucion 2", main="Barplot")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente, como se está usando el `par` si se quiere que vuelva a sus valores por defecto, se puede emplear antes de salir de **RStudio** o cuando lo consideres pertinente:

```
dev.off()
```

En este post [Reset par to the default values at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789982/reset-par-to-the-default-values-at-startup) se detalla más al respecto.